# Get the product ID of the last item Added to cart in WooCommerce cart page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, cart

I don't use ajax add to cart but rather redirect to cart page when user clicks add to cart. On the cart page I would like to run some javascript (gtag event add to cart) with data about the product that was added to cart.

I don't know how to get product id that was added. Like in `wc_add_to_cart_message` notice which prints the product that was successfully added to cart. I would need to get product id and run script on cart page.

So when it redirects to cart page I would need to get the product id that was added to cart for further use in javascript code.

Any help is appreciated.